# Cannot blacklist unfreeRedistributableFirmware

Tags: nixos

I want to blacklist `unfreeRedistributableFirmware` license because despite being nonfree, NixOS currently doesn't treat it as such. So I add this to my `configuration.nix`.

```
  boot = {
    kernelPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages_latest-libre;
    ...
  }
  nixpkgs.config = {
    allowBroken = true;
    blacklistedLicenses = with lib.licenses; [
      unfreeRedistributableFirmware
    ];
    ...
  };
```

However, I keep getting `firmware-linux-nonfree` error after running `nixox-rebuild` even though I declare Linux-libre kernel.

```
error: Package ‘firmware-linux-nonfree-2021-07-16’ in /nix/store/c84snp1irc764vsr81dcv61qrq78wdnv-nixos-21.05.2734.74d017edb67/nixos/pkgs/os-specific/linux/firmware/firmware-linux-nonfree/default.nix:23 has a blocklisted license (‘unfreeRedistributableFirmware’), refusing to evaluate.
```

Any tip or workaround will be appreciated.

Comment: If you pass `--show-trace` to nix command you're running (`nixos-rebuild`, presumably) you'll get a call trace that might give a clue. Did you set any [firmware-related options](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=21.05&show=hardware.firmware&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=firmware)?

Comment: @RobertHensing I didn't set that option. The `--show-trace` output looks very cryptic to me: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UHMLdBNtFSya0vylj89YNlyA1r0R8whU/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The module system's implementation causes more lines than one would hope to see, but it does provide extra context as well, also right in the stack trace. It seems that the `udev` module is responsible for evaluating the blocked package (somewhat near the end, ```while evaluating definitions from `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixos/modules/services/hardware/udev.nix':```)

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this imported module in /etc/nixos/hardware-configuration.nix

```
imports = [ (modulesPath + "/installer/scan/not-detected.nix") ];
```

This module contains `hardware.enableRedistributableFirmware = lib.mkDefault true;`. I just comment it out and all the non-free firmware are gone.

But that file can be overwritten by `nixos-generate-config` so it is better to declare `hardware.enableRedistributableFirmware = false;` in `configuration.nix` instead.